# VBA - Using .onAction on SmartArtNodes

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and trying to use smartArt.Nodes to dynamically generate an organizational chart based on some cell data. I am able to generate the chart with no problems. Now, I would like to be able to display more details of specific nodes of the chart by clicking on them. I am aware that we can convert smartArts into Shapes with the Drawing Tools in Excel and then use .onAction on them like:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(name1).OnAction = "detail"
```

However, is there a way to achieve the same thing with smartArt.nodes using VBA? Say I have a node called "nodes1" I have tried:

```
nodes1.Shapes.OnAction = "detail"
```

or

```
Dim objShape As Shape
Dim SmartArtNod As SmartArtNode
Set objShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
Set SmartArtNod = objShape.SmartArt.AllNodes(1)

SmartArtNod.Shapes(1).OnAction = "detail"
```

and other combinations, but none of them seem to work...
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For tips on writing great questions visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you have any questions about the site, you can visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) or visit [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @CodingNinja Do you think that the OP hasn't asked the question in a proper manner? If not, What's the point then redirecting the OP to other pages? Personally I feel that OP has asked the question in very appropriate manner. And if it's a canned reply, it should be tweaked then.

Comment: @sktneer Yes I agree, this is a good question. I noticed he was a new user, so I thought I would help him out. I never said the question was bad, I just thought It would be good to welcome him and give some sites to help him in the future.

Comment: @CodingNinja Welcoming the new member was a good gesture but then the rest of the statement spoiled it. What I feel is It was not relevant . :) Anyways thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: @sktneer Thank _you_. I have edited my welcome, so it's a little more warming, and helps the OP a little more.

Comment: I think you would need to make use of events here. More in particular the Worksheet_SelectionChange.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to prove a negative, but I believe this is not possible.  Testing with Excel 2013,  I can confirm the following do not work:

- Trying to trap the Selection of the SmartArt using
  `Worksheet_SelectionChanged` does not fire.  If you change the
  selection from a cell to the SmartArt object, you will not get an
  event.  You will get an event however when you lose focus on the
  SmartArt and go back to the cell.
- You can select a SmartArt object and then debug to check what is selected.  The object is of type
  `Object/Shape` and the watch window indicates that it exposes an
  `OnAction` property, but attempting to set this property will throw
  an error.

I take the two issues above to mean that is will be very difficult (if not impossible) to get an `OnAction` event to fire from the SmartArt.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try to see if there are any other ways I can display the details.